# How can I dynamically determine the variant of an enum

Tags: rust

I want to implement a module that encapsulates different types of messages with different types and quantity of fields that enables to send and receive them using the same `send` and `receive` functions, and then determine what variant of the message is, with what fields; using `match`.

I have the following enum and functions (simplified) :

```
pub enum Message {
  Start { field1 : type1 },
  End   { field2 : type2 },
}

impl Message {
  pub fn send( &self ) {
    send(self);
  }

  pub fn receive( &mut self ) {
    *self = receive();
  }
}
```

I want to use them as follows:

Send:

```
let message = Message::Start;
message.send();
```

Receive

```
let message = Message;
message.receive();
match message {
  Start{field1} => { ... }
  End{field2} => { ... }
};
```

When calling the `receive` function, I get a compiler error that says "*use of possibly-uninitialized `message`*". It makes sense because this variable has not been initialized. How can I achieve this behavior with no errors?

Comment: Are you sure you need `self` for `receive`? Can't it be an associated function `fn receive() -> Self`?

Comment: This is a strange pattern, in the sense that it doesn't make sense for an uninitialized instance of `Message` to exist. What is a default message supposed to be? Why should a message send and receive itself? Shouldn't it be the job of another component?

Comment: I agree with the other commenters. Your struct layout makes it really hard for the compiler to understand what's going on. It will never be able to figure out that `receive` is supposed to get an uninitialized `message` and initialize it. That's just not a feature of Rust.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you can technically do "out" parameters with `MaybeUninit<Message>` but that's fraught with perils and requires `unsafe`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Your approach makes more sense to me and seems correct instead of my initial thought

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an associated function which *returns* a `Message`.

```
impl Message {
  pub fn receive() -> Message {
    // Do whatever and return a Message::Start or Message::End as needed.
  }
}

// To call...
let my_message = Message::receive();
```

Associated functions are sort of like static functions in C++, and they use `::` on the type name itself as the call syntax. At runtime, it's just another ordinary function, but it's in the `Message` namespace so it's easier to find for programmers at write time.